# Repairing RAID6 with two drive issues mdadm

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid6

I have had two disk failures on my RAID6 array. I have added two new disks and did the following:

- I ran mdadm /dev/md1 --remove on the two disks
- I set up my RAID on the 1st partition of each disk (for alignment reasons). As the replacement disks are aligned the same, I did a dd if=/dev/sdg (working disk) of=/dev/sde (new disk) bs=512 count=1 to copy over the partition layout. **I am not sure if this is the right thing to do, as I probably copied mdadm superblock data.**
- I then ran mdadm /dev/md1 --add and the two disks.

I now have this when I run mdadm --detail /dev/md1:

```
Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
   1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   6       8       65        2      spare rebuilding   /dev/sde1
   3       0        0        3      removed
   4       8       97        4      active sync   /dev/sdg1
   5       8      113        5      active sync   /dev/sdh1

   7       8       81        -      spare   /dev/sdf1
```

/proc/mdstat shows one disk as rebuilding, but not the other. I don't think this is right, as I think one disk is 'removed' and hasn't been replaced properly. The drive letters are exactly the same as the last two disks. Here is mdstat.

```
root@precise:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[0] sdd1[1]
  1953379136 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid6 sdf1[7](S) sde1[6] sdb1[1] sdh1[5] sda1[0] sdg1[4]
  11720521728 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/4] [UU__UU]
  [>....................]  recovery =  2.2% (65163484/2930130432) finish=361.0min   speed=132257K/sec

unused devices: <none>`
```

I'd like to know (if this seems right), and what I need to do to fix the Number 3 entry and get /dev/sdf1 to take its place? I then assume that I will have a proper array again. What I find odd is adding /dev/sde1 seems to have allowed started a sync, but /dev/sdf1 has not taken the place of Number 3 Major 0 (RaidDevice 3)

All help appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

First, let me reassure you: if your mdadm drives are partition-based (eg: sda1, etc), the first "dd" was OK and it did not cause any mdadm metadata copy (the metadata are *inside* the partition itself, not inside the MBR).

What you are observing is normal MDRAID behavior. You re-added the new drives using two separate mdadm -a commands, right? In this case, mdadm will *first* resync the first drive (putting the second one to "spare" mode) and *then* it will transition the second drive to "rebuilding spare" status. If you re-add the two drives with a single command (eg: mdadm /dev/mdX -a /dev/sdX1 /dev/sdY1) the rebuild will run concurrently.

Let have a look at my (testing) failed RAID6 arraid:

```
[root@kvm-black test]# mdadm --detail /dev/md200
/dev/md200:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Feb  9 18:40:59 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 129024 (126.02 MiB 132.12 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 32256 (31.51 MiB 33.03 MB)
   Raid Devices : 6
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Feb  9 18:51:03 2015
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : localhost:md200  (local to host localhost)
           UUID : 80ed5f2d:86e764d5:bd6979ed:01c7997e
         Events : 105

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       7        0        0      active sync   /dev/loop0
       1       7        1        1      active sync   /dev/loop1
       2       7        2        2      active sync   /dev/loop2
       3       7        3        3      active sync   /dev/loop3
       4       0        0        4      removed
       5       0        0        5      removed
```

Re-adding the drives using two separate command (mdadm /dev/md200 -a /dev/loop6; sleep 1; mdadm /dev/md200 -a /dev/loop7) caused the following detailed report:

```
[root@kvm-black test]# mdadm --detail /dev/md200
/dev/md200:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Feb  9 18:40:59 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 129024 (126.02 MiB 132.12 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 32256 (31.51 MiB 33.03 MB)
   Raid Devices : 6
  Total Devices : 6
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Feb  9 18:56:40 2015
          State : clean, degraded, recovering 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 6
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 2

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

 Rebuild Status : 9% complete

           Name : localhost:md200  (local to host localhost)
           UUID : 80ed5f2d:86e764d5:bd6979ed:01c7997e
         Events : 134

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       7        0        0      active sync   /dev/loop0
       1       7        1        1      active sync   /dev/loop1
       2       7        2        2      active sync   /dev/loop2
       3       7        3        3      active sync   /dev/loop3
       6       7        6        4      spare rebuilding   /dev/loop6
       5       0        0        5      removed

       7       7        7        -      spare   /dev/loop7
```

After some time:

```
[root@kvm-black test]# mdadm --detail /dev/md200
/dev/md200:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Feb  9 18:40:59 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 129024 (126.02 MiB 132.12 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 32256 (31.51 MiB 33.03 MB)
   Raid Devices : 6
  Total Devices : 6
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Feb  9 18:57:43 2015
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 6
Working Devices : 6
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : localhost:md200  (local to host localhost)
           UUID : 80ed5f2d:86e764d5:bd6979ed:01c7997e
         Events : 168

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       7        0        0      active sync   /dev/loop0
       1       7        1        1      active sync   /dev/loop1
       2       7        2        2      active sync   /dev/loop2
       3       7        3        3      active sync   /dev/loop3
       6       7        6        4      active sync   /dev/loop6
       7       7        7        5      active sync   /dev/loop7
```

Adding the two drives in a single command (mdadm /dev/md200 -a /dev/loop6 /dev/loop7) leads to that report:

```
[root@kvm-black test]# mdadm --detail /dev/md200
/dev/md200:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Feb  9 18:40:59 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 129024 (126.02 MiB 132.12 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 32256 (31.51 MiB 33.03 MB)
   Raid Devices : 6
  Total Devices : 6
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Feb  9 18:55:44 2015
          State : clean, degraded, recovering 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 6
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 2

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

 Rebuild Status : 90% complete

           Name : localhost:md200  (local to host localhost)
           UUID : 80ed5f2d:86e764d5:bd6979ed:01c7997e
         Events : 122

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       7        0        0      active sync   /dev/loop0
       1       7        1        1      active sync   /dev/loop1
       2       7        2        2      active sync   /dev/loop2
       3       7        3        3      active sync   /dev/loop3
       7       7        7        4      spare rebuilding   /dev/loop7
       6       7        6        5      spare rebuilding   /dev/loop6
```

So, in the end: let mdadm do its magic, then check if all drives are marked as "active".

Comment: This is what I see now:

      
md1 : active raid6 sdf1[7](F) sde1[6](F) sdb1[1] sdh1[5] sda1[0] sdg1[4](F)
      11720521728 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/3] [UU___U]
      
unused devices: <none>

I think it has got worse!

Comment: It seems that another device failed while rebuilding. If this is true, sorry but data are gone: RAID6 can suffer a maximum of 2 concurrent disk failures; 3 failures can not be recovered.

Comment: This was really sad to read,